# VBA Excel “object variable or with block variable not set”

Tags: excel, vba

I keep getting the "object variable or with block variable not set" error with the below code. Code was working fine before I added the second function to it. Essentially it is taking data from one workbook and pasting it into a different workbook. Can someone please tell me how to fix it so the error goes away?

The line with the error is this one: Set wv = wc.Sheets("All Voucher Trips")

```
Dim SourceFolder As String, wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, rng1 As Range, wv As Worksheet, wc As Workbook ' The Dim keyword is short for Dimension. It is used to declare variables in VBA. Declare means we are telling VBA about a variable we will use later.

Set wb = GetWBName 
Set ws = wb.Sheets("Vouchers with Trips") 
Set wc = GetWCName
Set wv = wc.Sheets("All Voucher Trips")


strFileDir = ThisWorkbook.Path

SourceFolder = strFileDir

ws.UsedRange.Offset(1, 0).ClearContents

lr = wv.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 

Set rng1 = wv.Range("A2:W" & lr)

rng1.Copy ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) 


End Sub




Function GetWBName() As Workbook
    Dim wb As Workbook
    FileName = "220700"

    For Each wb In Application.Workbooks
        If wb.Name Like FileName & "*" Then
            Set GetWBName = wb
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next wb

End Function

Function GetWCName() As Workbook
    Dim wc As Workbook
    FileName = "VoucherActivity"

    For Each wc In Application.Workbooks
        If wc.Name Like "*" & FileName Then
            Set GetWCName = wc
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next wc

End Function
```

Comment: Save us some time and tell us which line errors please.

Comment: Just have one function and add an argument.

Comment: This one has the error: Set wv = wc.Sheets("All Voucher Trips")

Comment: Think you need `Set wc = GetWCName()`.

Comment: Then again if the first one doesn't error that probably isn't it. Maybe there's no workbook of that name - have you checked what the function returns?

Comment: Why would a function that "gets a name" return a `Workbook`? Consider renaming `GetWCName` => `GetWorkbookByName`, and passing the `FileName` as a parameter instead of duplicating the code. Also the function(s) are returning `Nothing` if the file isn't already opened, and the calling code isn't ensuring the returned object reference is actually set, hence error 91. Lastly you seem to be using undeclared variables, is `Option Explicit` specified?

Comment: Note that your two functions aren't the same: `VoucherActivity.xlsx` isn't going to match your `Like` condition, and that's probably your bug.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon can you please give me the code in the form you described? I'm a complete noob at this

Comment: He's pointing out the different position of the asterisk (which I had missed). Why is it different in the second function.

Comment: it's because the workbook name varies in the beginning of the string vs. the end of the string

Comment: Without the trailing asterisk, you're not matching the .xlsx/.xlsm file extension, hence the function returns `Nothing` unless you're looking for a workbook that isn't saved.

Comment: That function is supposed to be looking for a saved workbook with a variable first word in the filename

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I have no idea how to fix this - can someone please help out with some code?

Comment: `If wc.Name Like "*" & FileName & "*" Then`